# How to get both values from dropdown menu of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have to create search engine like in this site : http://olx.co.id . it has three keywords. First is searching by Item, second is searching by City, and the third is searching by Categories. Users can search with one keywords, two keywords, and three keywords. I did't have any Idea to do this. Here is my code but I am not sure it is working well or not.

```
    <form method="GET" action="category-grid.php">
    <div class="control-group">
    <input type="text" name="search_item_" class="search-field" placeholder="Searching Item ..." />
        <ul class="categories-filter animate-dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown">       
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" >All Cities</button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="city" >
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >Jakarta</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >Singapore</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" >Beijing</a></li>  
              </ul>                 
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="categories-filter animate-dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">All Categories</a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="category">
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Car</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Motorcycle</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Property</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Industry</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Elektronic & Gadget</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sport</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>

        <a class="search-button" href="<?php echo base_url();?>search" ></a>    

                    </div>
                </form>
```

my question is how  how to get the value of category when user changes the value of city or get the value of city when user changes the value of category.

```
<script>
var city; var category; var item=$('search_item').val();

$('#city li').on('click', function(){
   city = $(this).text();

   if(category == "") window.location.assign('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/searching/'+city);
   else window.location.assign('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/searching/'+city+'/'+category);
});
$('#category li').on('click',function(){
   $category = $(this).text();

   if(city == "") window.location.assign('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/searching/'+category);
   else window.location.assign('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/searching/'+lokasi+'/'+kategori);
});
<script>
```

Thanks for all comments and answers

Comment: The idea is that you have to actually write code to do the search. It doesn't magically happen if you have some html on a page. Where is your search code?

Comment: I didn't make it yet because I didn't know how to pass all value of the keywords

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use apache solr, it's a java based search engine.
I think woud work pretty good with the scenario you want.

[tutorial](http://heliosearch.org/solr/getting-started/)

[download](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

It's just my suggestion. If you like try it out.

Comment: How would you suggest one integrate this on a web page like the code above unless they can run the java app on their web server?